# C# sugar syntax for auto property

Tags: c#, syntax

I saw a viewo one time time where the following syntax is used in c#:

```
    class A
    {
        DateTime CreationDate
        {
            get;
            set => backing = value.Date;
        }
    }
```

The main thing is the **backing** keyword, of **backfiled**, I do not remember exactly. Is there something similar in C#? And when yes, in which version? Unfortunately I could not found it any C# reference document.

---

### **Update based on comments**

The following sample is working, But I do not want to create the backing field my own. I want to reach the backing field, which the compiler created.

```
    class A
    {
        DateTime CreationDate
        {
            get;
            set => backing = value.Date;
        }
        private DateTime backing;
   }
```

Comment: if you don't specify the getter, you don't need to specify the setter either (IMHO). So why not just `DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }` ?

Comment: Because the need to cut the time part when value is setted

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: I checked trhe curent reference already, maybe it comes with C# 10?

Comment: hmm... the 'DateTime.Date' is of Type  'DateTime' as well, so the only thing is, you set the Time-Portion to midnight. Does this really make a difference to you on storing the value? You may pass the DateTime.Date to the property when setting, or purge on getting... Anyway, if you need to handle getter/setter, you will need to declare the backing field (or declare Functions)... As far as I know...

Comment: Can't quite see what you are looking for and, if you think on it, what would the backing field be called? That could be messy. Lots of improvements in this area though.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10

Answer (score 0):

This could be the following, so for. But in C# 11, this may change:

```
internal class A
{
    private DateTime _creationDate;
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._creationDate;
        }
        set
        {
            this._creationDate = value.Date;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties can be used with [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members):

```
class YourClass
{
    private DateTime creationDate;
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get => this.creationDate;
        set => this.creationDate = value.Date;
    }
}
```

This looks almost like your code, except for the additional body in the getter implementation.

The `this`, of course, is optional, so it becomes even more alike to the code from your question:

```
class YourClass
{
    private DateTime creationDate;
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get => creationDate;
        set => creationDate = value.Date;
    }
}
```

Differences: `get;` becomes `get => creationDate;` (added arrow and backing field) and `set backing = value.Date;` becomes `set => creationDate = value.Date;` (added arrow and changed name of backing field)

Comment: This is the obvious implementation. But there is a possibility to reach the auto implemneted backfield. This i waht I lokking for

Comment: @GyörgyGulyás what is your goal? Not being able to access the backing field? In that case, wrap your field in a custom type which only exposes a getter for the value.